# Importing JSON file in Cucumber Protractor framework

Tags: json, import, protractor

I want to keep my test data in a JSON file that I need to import in cucumber-protractor custom framework. I read we can directly require a JSON file or even use protractor params. However that doesn't work. I don't see the JSON file listed when requiring from a particular folder.

testdata.json

```
{
    "name":"testdata",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "username":"1020201",
    "password":"1020201"
}
```

Code in the Config.js

```
onPrepare: function() {
  var data = require('./testdata.json');
},
```

I don't see the testdata.json file when giving path in require though its available at the location.

I wish to access JSON data using data.name, data.version etc.

Following is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Is the `testdata.json` inside same folder as `Config.js`?

Comment: Yes. Even if I put it in different folder and try to give a relative i.e. './foldername/testdata.json'. It doesn't work. I actually don't see that file when trying to give the path.

Comment: give a screenshot of your folder structure to illustrate the `testdata.json` and `config.js`  relationship, and the cmd window you run the case.  The given content in question is the all text in `testdata.json`?  If no, show all text in `testdata.json`.  One possible reason is your `testdata.json` is not a valid JSON file which includes wrong syntax.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot to the question. Have a look. I had validated my json too and was valid. The code to require in my config file is  global.data = require('./test_data/testdata.json')

Comment: I tried and worked on my local, check there is no space at heading or ending in file name `testdata.json` . If no, create another json file, just put `{}` in it and try require the new file.  Another way is open a cmd window and switch the `test_data` folder, then type `node` press enter, after that type `console.dir(require('testdata.json'))` to see what will happen

Comment: I tried the above. the problem is even is console I get module not found error.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'new.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: What's your nodejs version? and did you install the correct version of x64 or x86.

Comment: 8.9.4. I update it to the latest 8.11.3 too and tried but it did not work. I am using windows 10 and installed node 64 bit using msi.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your json file is located in the current directory & and in the same folder where your config file resides as you are giving this path `require('./testdata.json');` -

There are many ways of setting your data variables and accessing them globally in your test scripts -

**1st method**: Preferred method is to use node's global object -

```
onPrepare: function() {
   global.data = require('./testdata.json');
},
```

Now you could access `data` anywhere in your scripts.

**2nd Method** Is to use protractor's `param` object -

```
exports.config = {

params: {
    data: require('./testdata.json');
}
};
```

you can then access it in the specs/test scripts using `browser.params.data`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand these ways. the problem I face is it doesn't recognize the JSON when imported. I can only import the JS files. Do I need to install something to make it work? I am using node 8.9.4.

Comment: No you do not have to install anything and I didn't get the part- ` it doesn't recognize the JSON when imported`, did you try printing the data to console after importing?

Comment: Ok. I am using the Visual Studio Code IDE and what I mean that when I write require statement, it doesn't recognize the JSON file kept at the location. It only shows the JS files.

Comment: If you are talking about the intellisense not detecting the json file then this is nowhere an issue with protractor or cucumber. If you want the intellisense you should probably use typescript with commonjs module config!

Comment: Yes, You are right. but even if I go ahead and implement any of the method as you said. I get the data variable as undefined cause the require doesn't return the JSON data to it.